# How should method signatures be interpreted in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

For the [`ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper::Base` module](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Base.html#method-i-match), the `match` method is defined like this:

```
match(path, options=nil)
```

One thing I find challenging in the Rails documentation is that it doesn't tell me what the type of some of these parameters are. So let's look at some of the examples:

```
match ':controller/:action/:id'
```

Here, `path` is a string.

```
match 'songs/*category/:title' => 'songs#show'
```

Here, it's a hash. Or is it a string still? I'm not sure how to interpret this syntax. Is it:

```
{ match 'songs/*category/:title' => 'songs#show' }
```

where `match 'songs/*category/:title'` is the key and `'songs#show'` is the value? Or:

```
match {'songs/*category/:title' => 'songs#show'}
```

where the `match` method is being called with a hash as the first argument?

Answer (score 2):

It's either a string or a hash. And it's the second one:

```
  match {'songs/*category/:title' => 'songs#show'}
```

But the hash is actually an argument, so more correctly it would be:

```
  match({'songs/*category/:title' => 'songs#show'})
```

You can try that yourself with a mock method in the irb:

```
irb(main):005:0> def match(foo)
irb(main):006:1>   puts foo
irb(main):007:1> end
=> nil
irb(main):008:0> match "somestring"
somestring
=> nil
irb(main):009:0> match :has => "hash"
{:has=>"hash"}
=> nil
```

Comment: Ok, I added a clarification.

Answer (score 0):

It is a hash as in

```
match({'songs/*category/:title' => 'songs#show'})
```

At the final argument position, you can omit the `{}`. But you cannot write it like

```
match {'songs/*category/:title' => 'songs#show'}
```

because the `{}` will be interpreted as a block, and will cause a syntax error without `()`, which explicitly indicates that it is an argument.

Answer (score 0):

For `match ':controller/:action/:id'`, `path is a String.

For `match 'songs/*category/:title' => 'songs#show'`, `path` is a Hash:

```
1.9.3p125 :001 > def match(path, options=nil)
1.9.3p125 :002?>   puts path
1.9.3p125 :003?>   puts options
1.9.3p125 :004?> end
 => nil 
1.9.3p125 :005 > match 'foo' => 'bar'
{"foo"=>"bar"}

 => nil
```

Comment: But it’s not *always* a hash.

Comment: Right, I was just referring to the part the original post was asking about, since there didn't seem to be any doubt that, in the very first case, `path` is a String. Nevertheless I've updated my post to clarify